# What is the difference between $x+\sqrt{x^2}$ and $2x$?

Tags: functions

A few days back, I went through a simple thing which was obvious, but it made me think when I was adding two functions. That thing is as follows:
$$x=x,\quad\forall  x\in \mathbb R$$
dividing by $x$ on both sides  $$\frac xx=1,\quad\forall x\in \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$$
You see the domain changes just after multiplication. The same thing happens in $\sqrt{ab}$ and $\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}$, but I figured out the difference, (conversion from former to later).

---

Now I am stuck with the difference and possible restriction from converting a function from $f(x)=x+\sqrt {x^2}\quad$ to $\quad g(x)=2x$.

**What are the differences between $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x^2}$ and $g(x)=2x$?**

One difference I found out:

> 1)  $g(x)$ is bijective, whereas $f(x)$ is neither a one-one nor an onto function, which is I think significant.

Conclusion from answers:

> 2) $x>0$

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x| \neq x$ for all $x$, only non-negative $x$.

Comment: When $x$ is negative $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @SimonS : or zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To oversimplify, do both cases:

$$x+\sqrt{x^2}-2x=\begin{cases}x+x-2x=0\;,\;\;x\ge0\\{}\\x-x-2x=-2x\;,\;\;x<0\end{cases}$$

since by definition

$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=\begin{cases}x\;\;\;\,,\;\;x\ge0\\{}\\-x\;,\;\;x<0\end{cases}$$